# How to get this particular piece content from a webpage?

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to get data from an webpage for an program written in Java I'm working on but for some reason i can't seem to figure out how to do it the right way.

This is the piece of HTML:

[image]

And all I need to get the word "Crush".

What is the best way to do this in Java?

Comment: You have `java` as a tag, `html-parsing` as another, and mention `javascript`... all I see is HTML. What language are you trying to do this with?

Comment: I need to get the data using Java.

Comment: Haha yeah he means how to parse html from a webpage in JAVA, but to much people are editing

Comment: I've used jsoup for this before - but really just choose a library of your liking. SO isn't the best place to recommend tools.

Comment: @PietJetse what have you tried so far? Have you Googled about how you can parse `HTML` in `Java`?

Comment: I got the code as an String and i tried to manipulate the string using methods like StartsWith, contains and replace.

Comment: You can use `regex` to find the required text.

Comment: @PietJetse why are you reinventing the wheel? Please do a Google search before posting a question.

Comment: Does the webpage have a unique div/span for the data you're trying to get at? If the span is not unique and/or changes frequently then there's not much point trying to parse it

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that will do this for you.

You could always use a combination of the native Java libraries to accomplish this. You can read the HTML from an input stream one line at a time and do a string.contains("Crush")

Comment: This is what i tried but "Crush" does change from time to time.

Comment: What changes? And as a follow up, what specifically are you looking for in the html?